# getting data from multiple tables mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello I have four tables

```
 - Questions 
 - Answers
 - User 
 - Connections
```

Relationship

- User -> OneToMany->Question
- Question - > OneToMany - >Answers
- User -> OneToMany-> Connections

I want to get actually the questions  of user connections. 
So basically get questions from the questions table and also get those questions also which user's connections has answered.

To explain you in detail what I want is

each user has connections meaning friends.
I have a screen called "Questions". On that Screen I want to show those questions which user's friends asked and also those questions which user's friends answered.

This is the query which I am trying

```
SELECT * FROM connection
JOIN user ON user.user_id=connection.connected_user_id
LEFT JOIN direct_question ON direct_question.questioner_user_id=user.user_id 
LEFT JOIN direct_answer ON direct_answer.answerer_user_id =user.user_id
WHERE connection.user_id= 40
```

But this query isn't showing me correct data

The result I am getting this.

[image]

If you see answers table. there has been answer given by one of user's connection whose question id is 7. So It should get the question also which has id 7

[image]

Question Table

[image]

Connection Table

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated

Comment: @Thernys I don't understand?

Comment: You want to have a list with all questions asked by friends and a list with all answers given by friends?

Comment: @sauerburger yes exactly

Comment: Then doesn't it make more sense to have two separate queries, one for questions and one for answers?

Comment: @sauerburger isn't it possible to do only one and get the results ?

Comment: This will result in a mess imho. If a question has multiple answers, the information about the question will be contained multiple times in the result (once per answer).